# Pythonic way to get boolean value of object

Tags: python

I'd like opinions on the most idiomatic way to write a function that returns `True` if an object is truthy, and `False` otherwise.  For example:

```
is_truthy(True) # True
is_truthy(False) # False
is_truthy(123) # True
is_truthy(0) # False
is_truthy("some string") # True
is_truthy("") # False
```

The best I've come up with is this:

```
def is_truthy(obj):
    return not not obj
```

Can anybody do better?

Comment: The most pythonic way would be to not write a function for something that you can use in an expression directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
is_truthy = bool
```

The builtins got you covered.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
bool(obj)
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please include how/why your post will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a `bool` it's because you will end up using it in `if` statements and the like. I don't think you need to encapsulate anything within an *is truthy* function;  just use the `bool` directly. I.e. rather than:

```
if is_truthy(my_bool):
    # do something
```

simply do:

```
if my_bool:
    # do something
```

Comment: Thanks -- I'm aware of that.  I don't need to use the value in a comparison.  Instead, I've got a function that should return True or False, based on the return value of an intermediate function.  The caller of the function doesn't need to know about the intermediate function, nor its return value, hence this question.

Comment: @grifaton Maybe `True and retval_of_intermediate_func()` is better? I.e. using the `and` operator with `True`. But this is a matter of taste. Why not return the value of the intermediate function directly; or else make the intermediate function called directly by the outer function.